# How to increase the table height from the code behind file in ASP.Net while using StringWriter?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I am generating one PDF from the Code Behind File using StringWriter and HtmlTextWriter.
The Coding is given below:

```
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None; 
gv.DataSource = dt2;
gv.DataBind();
gv.RenderControl(hw);
string str = sw.ToString();
string str1 = "<table width='100%' border='1'><tr><td><img src='" + Server.MapPath("App_Themes/Ribo/ribologo.bmp") + "' alt='' width=75px height=75px /></td><td align='center' colspan='8' font size='3'><h2><b>MATERIAL RECEIPT CUM INSPECTION REPORT(MRIR)</b></h2</td></tr>";
str1 += "<tr><td font size='3'>MRIR NO</td><td font size='3'>Date</td><td align='center' font size='3'>JOB DESCRIPTION</td><td font size='3'>SUPPLIER NAME</td><td font size='3'>DC NO</td><td font size='3'>DATE</td><td font size='3'>LWB NO/DATE</td><td font size='3'>INVOICE NO</td><td font size='3'>DATE</td></tr>";
str1 += "<tr><td font size='3'>" + txtMRVNumber.Text + "</td><td font size='3'></td><td font size='3'></td><td font size='3'>" + TDSSVendor.Text + "</td><td font size='3'>" + txtDCNumber.Text + "</td><td font size='3'></td><td font size='3'>" + txtLWBNo.Text + "</td><td font size='3'>" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "</td><td font size='3'></td></tr>";
str1 += "<tr><td rowspan='2' font size='3'>DESCRIPTION</td><td font size='3' colspan='2' align='center'>SIZE(mm)</td><td colspan='6'></td></tr>";
str1 += "<tr><td font size='3' colspan='2'>" + sw + "</td><td colspan='6'></td></tr></table>";           

if (str.StartsWith("<div>"))
{
    str = str1;
}
System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(str);
iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 40f, 10f, 40f, 2f);
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker htmlparser = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
```

Here, I generated my desired PDF. But the table is displaying at the top of the PDF. So I want to display at the centre of the PDF as well as I want to increase the height of the Table. How to do this?

I tried like the below:

```
 string str1 = "<table **height='100%'** width='100%' border='1'><tr>.....
```

But it displays as the same. How to increase the height of the table? I need all your suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That alone is not going to do it. You can wrap the generated .pdf in another table (1 row, 1 column), and place that table in the sole TD of the new table, then just vertical align (valign='middle') the enclosing TD.

This is the only way I know how to do what you are asking, although I do not know if it will work for you:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Untitled Page</title>

<!-- Put this on your presentation page -->
            <style type="text/css">
                html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    border: none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table style="height: 100%" width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">


                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="middle">
                                <!-- Embed your .pdf here -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: BTW - the above would work in a browser, but who knows what will happen when the HTML is converted to .pdf; you will have to change the table "height" using css also, there is no height attrib on the table tag.

Comment: OK. How to increase the Height?

Comment: I tried like the below:         string str1 = "<table style='height: 800px'><tr><td><table width='100%' border='1'>...                    But still it gives the same o/p.

Comment: @thevan - see my updated snippet - I misunderstood what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

from the taking the height of the table u can set parameter of below Document class constructor.

```
Dim doc As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 1, 0, 0, 30)
```

Hope this will helps you...